# What's the difference between 只 and 才？

Tags: usage, difference, adverbs

What's the difference between 只 and 才?  When should I use 只 and when 才?

Can you give me some examples please?

Answer (score 2):

只 is equivalent to "only", a small amount. You would use it to say something like "I have only five bucks", "he's only two years old".

才 is used if you have to have a minimum amount. Examples: "you must be this tall (or taller) to ride", "you have to wait three minutes (or longer)".

Comment: I like the breakdown, but an example in Chinese for 只 and 才 would be nice.

Comment: "He's only two years old." would be 他才两岁 in Chinese, the example doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

He has 3 apples, but I just 1:

> 他有3个苹果，但我“才”1个。
> 他有3个苹果，但我“只有”1个。

“才” is stronger than “只”，“才”1个 means that you hope you can get more apples. “只有”1个 just says you have one, with no other meaning.

Answer (score 1):

All these explanations come from:

http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%E6%89%8D-%E5%8F%AA-%E5%B0%B1-to-emphasise-small-amounts.1921000/
  《

"只"
If you use 只(only), that means the amount is little. It's just an objective description.

"才"
...you'll see that used in the sense of "more than expected", 才 follows the amount or time; [b]
and if 才 precedes the amount or time, the amount or time has the sense of "less than expected". [a]

1.a 从这里到邮局才三分钟 (才 precedes the amount of time)
1.b 车开了三十分钟才到。(才 follows the amount of time)

2.a 我们去玩儿了两天，才花了一百块 (才 precedes the amount of money )
2.b 我一共花了三百块才买到这个。(才 follows the amount of money)

》

- And I would add for example 2b :
  we can also consider that 才 precedes the amount of purchased goods (这个) so the meaning is also "less goods than expected"

wordreference, same link again :
《 However, if we look at the word 只, usage is possible in the following manner:
从这里到邮局只需要三分钟 -- need to add in words like 需要, 用.//
我们去玩儿了两天，只花了一百块。》

- more objective, less feelings
  .
  Beware , concerning the other sentences,    只买  只到 would not be correct. 
  It's definitely  才买  才到  .

frequently used :
 只有 the amount is little
 只是 the level is low

Comment: I feel like 'budding' can also work for 才.  With two meanings of 'talented' (as in budding actress) and 'only just' (as in budding plant).  I came to that conclusion because the etymology of the character is a seed sprouting from the ground meaning 'to bud'.